# Add character to the beginning of a cell that start with number

Tags: excel

I need to add `_` to the beginning of any cell that begins with a number.

Before:

```
example123
123example
example456
```

After:

```
example123
_123example
example456
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following formula.  Assuming the data were in cell `A1`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1, 1))), "_"&A1, A1)
```

Comment: it is `ISNUMBER` and `LEFT` returns a string so you will need to try to convert it to a number for the `ISNUMBER` to work.  `=IF(ISNUMBER(--LEFT(A1)),"_"&A1,A1)`

Comment: @Scott `VALUE()` seems to work here, thanks for not downvoting me.

Comment: Why would I downvote?  You were on the right track.  Just needed a little help, isn't that what this site is for?  As to `VALUE()` vs `--`.  I personally prefer the latter as it is less typing for these weary old hands.

Comment: Just another note:  the `1` on LEFT is the default and can be left off, but again that is a personal preference.